# Show/Hide overlapping content <tr> below the previous <tr> inside Table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd want to implement a function Show/hide onMouseOver() with jquery that make me appear a second  below the first without to change the number of `<tr>` in a table (I mean that the dynamic `<tr>` 
it must overlap below the existing one). About this matter something i've already found. I've tried to implement the same solution with css...but i'm getting  "Flickering table" problem.
What is the best solution for resolving it?

html code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="hover-cell" data-target="#hidden_123">Hover this...</td>
        <td class="hidden" id="hidden_123">Hidden...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="hover-cell" data-target="#hidden_456">Hover this...</td>
        <td class="hidden" id="hidden_456">Hidden...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="hover-cell" data-target="#hidden_789">Hover this...</td>
        <td class="hidden" id="hidden_789">Hidden...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$('table').on('mouseover', '.hover-cell', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).show();
}).on('mouseout', '.hover-cell', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).hide();
});
```

css code

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

jsfiddle-->http://jsfiddle.net/jan7ajpy/

image .

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example of the exact result you are trying to achieve? I could only assume you want the "hidden" text to overlap the next row's text which would be "...Hover this...". Could you perhaps provide us with the code you already tried?

Comment: Hi. the code is the fiddle that i've shared..here :  http://jsfiddle.net/jan7ajpy/                          i've tried in the same way the you suggest me...but doesn't work.

Comment: @Barrosy i've almost resolved....i could use a z-index.....in this way the "td hidden" is overlapped...but the problem is that the below content is not disappier....how can hide the below content showing only the td-content? here the fiddle update--->jsfiddle.net/mhgfzw54/9 – Markus just now   edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question and I am correct in understanding what you are trying to seek, maybe this would be helpful. I used jQuery to hide the row and show another element in its place on hover. Please hover your cursor over first given element to see the example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".example").hide();
  $("tr:first-of-type td:first-of-type").hover(function() {
    $(".example").show();
    $("tr:nth-of-type(3) td").hide();
    $("tr:nth-of-type(4) td").css('padding-top', '20px');
  }, function() {
    $(".example").hide();
    $("tr:nth-of-type(3) td").show();
    $("tr:nth-of-type(4) td").css('padding-top', '0');
  });
});
```

```css
.example {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="example">
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>something</td>
    <tr>
      <td>some other data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        foobar
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If this is something you are looking for but not exactly what you mean, please do let me know.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e3ocuwy/)

Comment: i'd have  two question about your solution:                                                                               i'm tried to modify your code to make more similar at my table.                                                      -why if i adding some more<td>the content hiden have the 'widht' fixed?i mean  that  when appear the row the element is not the same width than other content td.                                                                                                                                                     -my project have angularjs.how can set-up together?

Comment: this is the fiddle that i've modified---> https://jsfiddle.net/t2fohvqs/15/

Comment: @Markus This is because the element with the example class has a property called "position". See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp as reference. Position makes an element behave differently when changed from static to something else and you might want to fiddle around with that.

Comment: perfect!. sorry the last things....could you show me on the same example the Hide/show for the second tr?..because i'm not understant how it work "nth-of-type". Here the fiddle modified--->https://jsfiddle.net/t2fohvqs/59/

Comment: @Markus I used `nth-of-type` just to select elements in which they are ordered to show you an example that it's possible. It's up to you how to use the example code to apply it to however you want it. You do not have to use or understand that (`nth-of-type`) part of the code to get the same thing work for you. You could basically use ID selectors or even classes. It was just for the sake of simplicity. Here is your example, you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mb91f704/ or something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pydo6mu2/

Comment: If you really are requiring to know more regarding `nth-of-type` you might want to check out: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hover-cell:hover + .hidden`

[learn about `+`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

To set it below use:`.hover-cell:hover{display:block;}`

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.hover-cell:hover,.hover-cell:hover + .hidden{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>...</td>
        <td class="hover-cell" data-target="#hidden_123">Hover this...</td>
        <td class="hidden" id="hidden_123">Hidden...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>...</td>
        <td class="hover-cell" data-target="#hidden_456">Hover this...</td>
        <td class="hidden" id="hidden_456">Hidden...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>...</td>
        <td class="hover-cell" data-target="#hidden_789">Hover this...</td>
        <td class="hidden" id="hidden_789">Hidden...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hello, i've tried this solution...but also with css solution the result not change...the content appear next to tr end under tr                                                                                http://jsfiddle.net/kzsexwgn/

Comment: how come adding another <td> the table get a resize?....is possible to get the same size  adding anyway under the "previus td"  another "td"?

Comment: i've almost resolved....i could use a z-index.....in this way the "td hidden" is overlapped...but the problem is that the below content is not disappier....how can hide the below content showing only the td-content?                                                          here the fiddle update--->http://jsfiddle.net/mhgfzw54/9/

Comment: I think OP means to show the second `<td>` element of a row and show it below that row above its next row whilst hiding that row (using JavaScript or/and CSS). Although I am not certain, maybe other solutions would be possible in order to achieve this as well.